How to upload multiple images from laravel api to vuejs
I want to upload multiple image using vuejs but in inspect it show in the picture :
{image.0: Array(1)}
image.0
: 
['The image.0 field is required.']
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

this is my code:
const form = ref({
  asset_item_id: '',
  image_url: [],
  note: '',
  value: '',
  unit: '',
  usercode: '',
})

const addLogAsset = async() => {
  if(loading.value) return

  console.log('add Log asset')

  loading.value = !loading.value  

try{
const res = await $api('/api/a/add/itemtrack', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        asset_item_id: form.value.asset_item_id,
        image: form.value.image_url,
        note: form.value.note,
        value: form.value.value,
        unit: form.value.unit,
        usercode: form.value.usercode,
      },
      onResponseError({ response }){
        console.log('onResponseError', response)
      },
    })

    const { status, data, message } = res

    if(status == "OK"){
      dialog.value = false
      emits('updateDone', true)
      form.value.asset_item_id = ''
      form.value.image_url = []
      form.value.note = ''
      form.value.value = ''
      form.value.unit = ''
      form.value.usercode = ''
    }else{
      emits('updateErr', message)
      console.log(message)
    }

    loading.value = false
  }catch(err){
    
    console.log(err)
    loading.value = false
  }
}


this is my template:
<v-file-input
  v-model="form.image_url"
  label="Photo"
  variant="filled"
  multiple
></v-file-input>  

I think my laravel code has no problem because I have tried with postman and it work succesfully. I think it problem with my frontend. I hope you guys can help me :)
